# SQL Update with PowerShell

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, sql-update, jobs

Below is my script and I have a problem updating finished jobs in the table, it only updates one job 5 times even though I update it by "WHERE ID", I can't figure out what is the issue or how to fix it

```
$connectionstring = "Server=localhost;Database=testDB;Trusted_Connection=True;"
$connection=New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$connection.ConnectionString=$connectionstring
$connection.Open()
$jobs=@()
$testOutput="C:\Users\tarik.gacanovic\Desktop\outfile.txt"

$query1 = "SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;"
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ConnectionString $connectionstring -Query $query1

$count="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Tasks WHERE Enabled='1'"

$maxConcurrentJobs=5
$jobsTotalresult=Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance 'localhost' -Database 'testDB' -Query $count
$jobsTotal=$jobsTotalresult.Column1



$SQLQueryID="SELECT ID FROM Tasks WHERE Enabled=1"
$SQLIDCommand=New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand ($SQLQueryID, $connection)

$SQLQuerySELECT="SELECT ExecPath, Param1, Param2, Param3 FROM Tasks WHERE Enabled=1"
$SQLselectCommand=New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand ($SQLQuerySELECT, $connection)

$tID=$SQLIDCommand.ExecuteScalar() 
$SQLReader=$SQLselectCommand.ExecuteReader()

$data = @()
while($SQLReader.Read()){
    $row = @{
        ExecPath = $SQLReader.GetString(0)
        Param1 = $SQLReader.GetString(1)
        Param2 = $SQLReader.GetString(2)
        Param3 = $SQLReader.GetString(3)
    }
    $data += New-Object PSObject -Property $row
    $jobsTotal=$data.Count
}
$SQLReader.Close()
$q=0

function JobCompleted($receivedState) {
    write-host 'JOBCOMPLETED WITH' $receivedState
    
    if($receivedState.State -eq 'Completed') { 
        $Status=2
        $Note=$q
        $Finished=$job.PSEndTime
        $ID=$receivedState.Id
        #$Note="Task finished successfully '$jid'"
        $SQLQueryUPDATE="UPDATE TaskLogs SET Status=$Status, Finished=getdate() WHERE ID=$rid"
        $SQLUPDATEcmd=New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($SQLQueryUPDATE, $connection)
        $SQLUPDATEcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        $SQLQueryUPDATE | out-file -FilePath $testOutput -Append
    }
    elseif($receivedState -eq 'Failed') {
        $Status=3
        #$Note="Task failed"
    }
    elseif ($receivedState -ne 'Completed' -or $receivedState -ne 'Failed') {
        $Status=9
        #$Note="NOT DEFINED"
    }
}

foreach($currow in $data){
    while(($jobs | Where-Object{$_.State -eq 'Running'}).Count -ge $maxConcurrentJobs){
        start-sleep -Milliseconds 500
    }
 
    $env:Path=$currow.ExecPath
    $job=Start-Job -scriptblock {& $env:Path}
    $jobs+=$job
        
    foreach($runningjob in $job){
            $rid=$runningjob.Id
        if($runningjob.State -eq 'Running'){
            
            $Status=1
            $Note="R--, " + $runningjob.Name
            $Created=$runningjob.PSBeginTime
        }

        $SQLQueryWRITE="INSERT INTO TaskLogs(ID, tID, Status, Created, Finished, Note) Values($rid, $tID, $Status, getdate(), null, '$Note')" 
        $SQLWRITEcmd=New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($SQLQueryWRITE, $connection)
        $SQLWRITEcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        $SQLQueryWRITE | out-file -FilePath $testOutput -Append
          
        Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $runningjob StateChanged -Action {
            $currentState=$EventArgs.JobStateInfo
            JobCompleted($currentState, $rid)
            Unregister-Event $eventsubsciber.SourceIdentifier
        }


        
    }
}
```

I have a problem updating finished jobs in the table, it only updates one job 5 times even though I update it by "WHERE ID", I can't figure out what is the issue or how to fix it

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code to actually see the parameter values change?

Comment: @ThomA but even if that is the problem which probably is, I don't know how to fix it

Comment: But when you step through you'll be able to find out where the assignment is failing, and then let *us* know which line specifically isn't working as you expect.

Comment: @ThomA okay I did it, so it seems the last job id in the batch is being used for all activities for update because it is the last one that is "taken" by the variable even tho the call of the jobcompleted function is within the foreach loop. Any else info you might need? Thanks!

Comment: `ExecuteScalar()` will return a single value. You have more than one job id, right?

Comment: @vonPryz yes, i have 4 batches of 5 jobs and for each one  i need an update to the correct row

Comment: @vonPryz 
I have now made the $rid an array, but I don't know where to go from here

Comment: @ThomA
I have now made the $rid an array, but I don't know where to go from here